# Restricting cache-storage for IIS server-side webrequests

Tags: iis, cache, internet-explorer

We have several old websites running classic asp that invokes a series of HTTP-request to external systems (in this case, geo-ip-lookup). This is just a single request, resulting in a country-code as a response (2 bytes), but since a webrequest on a web-page invokes (what I assume atleast) an ActiveX-instance of IE, it will cache this in "Temporary Internet Files", assumingly as the user "NETWORK SERVICE".

It stores all these responses in C:\WINDOWS\Temp\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5, but I haven't figured out a way to restrict the amount of space it should be allowed to use.

I'm not even sure if that would help, since the main problem is the 2-byte response, which "disk-wise" will utilize 1kb of space (cluster size) per cached response.

I could of course schedule a task that would clear out the cache, but I would rather disable it, or just limit it to a reasonable amount of space. But how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use ServerXMLHTTP instead of the ActiveX version of XMLHttpRequest (or equivalent).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759169(v=vs.85).aspx

Basically:

```
var objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject ("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");
```

Or whatever version you have installed ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP" or "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP" are other variants for different versions), then utilize this as any XMLHttpRequest.